# How to setup SonarQube scanner in jenkins for a js/ts/react project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jenkins, sonarqube

I would like to have Sonar scanner running on my project when it builds in jenkins.

Something like this,
[image: Something like this]

Most of the tutorials seem to only address this process from a Java perspective, So I am wondering how this can be done if at all.

I am doing some of the work out of a Jenkinsfile in my project:

```
stage('SonarQube') {
  environment {
    scannerHome = tool 'SonarQubeScanner'
  }
  steps {
    withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQubeScanner') {
      sh "${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner"
    }
  }
}
```

I used the following link to get the project in SonarQube: https://nickkorbel.com/2020/02/05/configuring-sonar-with-a-create-react-app-in-typescript/

I get a couple different errors when the scan tries to run during the Jenkins Build:

Error 1

```
Could not find executable in "/opt/app-root/src/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner".

Proceed with download of the platform binaries for SonarScanner...
 Creating /opt/app-root/src/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner

Downloading from https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.4.0.2170-linux.zip

(executable will be saved in cache folder: /opt/app-root/src/.sonar/native-sonar-scanner)

ERROR: impossible to download and extract binary: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

Error 2

```
ERROR: Failed to download https://binaries.sonarsource.com/Distribution/sonar-scanner-cli/sonar-scanner-cli-4.4.0.2170-linux.zip from agent; will retry from master

SonarQube installation defined in this job (sonarqube) does not match any configured installation. Number of installations that can be configured: 1.
```

Answer (score 3):

Error 2 is about missing integration with sonarqube server.

Full install of sonarqube:

1. Install SonarQube server
2. Install the SonarQube Scanner plugin for Jenkins.
3. Configure your SonarQube server(s):

- Log into Jenkins as an administrator and go to Manage Jenkins > Configure System.
- Scroll down to the SonarQube configuration section, click Add SonarQube, and add the values you're prompted for.
- The server authentication token should be created as a 'Secret Text' credential.

`withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQubeScanner')` - "SonarQubeScanner" means the name of the Sonarqube server from step 3.

In the pipeline you should pass parameters for sonar-scanner tool, for example:

```
stage('SonarQube analysis') {
        environment {
            scannerHome = tool 'SonarQube_4.3.0'
        }
        steps {
            withSonarQubeEnv('Your Sonar Server Name here') {
                sh '''
                ${scannerHome}/bin/sonar-scanner \
                -D sonar.projectKey=YOUR_PROJECT_KEY_HERE \
                -D sonar.projectName=YOUR_PROJECT_NAME_HERE \
                -D sonar.projectVersion=YOUR_PROJECT_VERSION_HERE \
                -D sonar.languages=js,ts \  // DEPRECATED, do not use this option
                -D sonar.sources=./src \
                -D sonar.test.inclusions=YOUR_INCLUSIONS_HERE \
                -D sonar.exclusions=YOUR_EXCLUSIONS_HERE
                '''
            }
        }
    }
```

Suppose Error 1 will be fixed after you fix Error 2.
Take a look at official documentation [here](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/scan/sonarscanner-for-jenkins/)

Comment: If you're referencing `SonarQube_4.3.0, you are probably using LTS 7.9.x or 8.x. in that case, `sonar.languages` is deprecated. SQ will analyze all languages fornwhich language plugins are installed. Make sure JavaScript, TypeScript SQ plugins installed.

Answer (score -1):

In my case any ways to init `scannerHome` var were unsuccessful. So I did it my way:

```
stage("SonarQube analysis") {
    steps {
        script {
            withSonarQubeEnv('SonarQube Server') {
                sh '''
                  ${JENKINS_HOME}/tools/hudson.plugins.sonar.SonarRunnerInstallation/SonarQube_Scanner/bin/sonar-scanner \
                   -Dsonar.host.url=URL_TO_SONAR \
                   -Dsonar.login=SONAR_TOKEN \
                   -Dsonar.projectKey=PROJECT_KEY \
                   -Dsonar.projectName=PROJECT_NAME
                '''
            }
        }
    }
}
```